# display:inline-flex resizing to child contents but can't use in react-native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have put a demo of what I want to achieve with a flex layout here:

https://jsfiddle.net/airwalker/zjd730x7/

Essentially my layout works when using

```
{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

but not

```
{
  display: flex;
}
```

In short I want the behaviour of the display: inline-flex where the container will resize to the child content but still be constrained with a max-width.

However I am using react-native which does not support the full flexbox specification, and does not support inline-flex.

What other way could I achieve my desired output using CSS?

Many thanks

Comment: Your example works as designed. In order to have both "Short" and "Medium" being restrained to a total max-width of 400px, you need to have an additional parent item.

Comment: check this, may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142761/display-inline-equivalent-in-react-native

Comment: The desired outcome is for the container to expand according to the content length upto a maximum of the max-width where the content then wraps.  In the case that it is very short content, the container has a size of min-width. So yes it works in the case of inline-flex.  If I am honest I am not actually sure why it works which is why I am struggling to reason about how to achieve the outcome without using display: inline-flex;

Comment: Actually I can, an inline element has no width or height right it is determined by the content, hence my inline block example works.  So I understand why it works, I probably just need to take a different approach to the original markup/layout.